# Product of First primitive roots equal to 1001

Tags: number-theory

The First three primitive roots of 71 are: 7, 11, 13, in ascending order.

The product $7\cdot 11\cdot 13=1001$.

Can It be proven that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that the product of their First three primitive roots in ascending order  Is $1001$?
Is there any other prime greater than 71 with this feature?

Comment: Please edit for context.  Is there any reason to imagine that this has a sensible answer?  As you are probably aware, very little is known about primes for which any specific natural number is a primitive root.  If you are actually interested in this question, I suggest a numerical search.  It's not likely anything concrete can be demonstrated about the behavior for large primes.

Answer (score 2):

I found another prime with the first three primitive roots $7,11,13$, namely
$$
p=2039.
$$
So $p$ has $\phi(\phi(2039))=1018$ primitive roots, starting with
$$
7, 11, 13, 14, 19, 21, 22, 26, 28, 33, 35, 38, 39, 41, 42, 44, 47, 52, 55, 56, 57, 61,\ldots , 2037.
$$

Comment: maybe if any other prime p exists with this feature, has it to have the form 200...39?

Comment: No, why should this be the case?

Comment: @Dietich Burde I only conjectured for primes >71